# Insert multiple values into database in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables branch and roadname each branch have many roadnames. I need to add this roadname on the selected branch. One branch can have multiple roads. I am not able to insert the values please guide me through.

**Table branch:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47mjo.png)

**Roadname**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT4IS.png)

Here is my code:

**Blade**

```
@section('content');

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <form id="roadnames" action="{{route('addroad',[$branch[0]->id])}}" method="POST">
        <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">

        <table id ="add">
            <tr>
                <thead>
                    <th>RoadName</th>
                </thead>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="roads[]" id="road"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button id="add_road" class="btn btn-primary"> Add More</button>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit"/>        

    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#add_road").on("click", function(){
        
            $('#add tr:last').clone().appendTo('#add');
        
});
});
</script>


@endsection
```

**Controller**

```
    public function addroads(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $resultset =  DB::select('select * from table_branch where id = ?',[$id]);

        $roadname = $request->input('roads');
        $branch_id = $id;

        $arr = array($roadname,$branch_id);

        if(DB::table('roadname')->insert($arr))
            {
                echo "Records inserted";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Records not inserted";
            }


        return view('addroads',array('branch'=>$resultset));

    }
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/admin/road/addrecord/{id}', '\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@addroads')->name('addroad');
```

Comment: can you post what you get in dd($request->all())

Comment: @JohnLobo its returning an empty array

Comment: also post addroad routes and table structure

Comment: Yes added now can you guide

Comment: are you using any eloquent relationship??

Comment: Yes. I have created Models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create models for each table  using php artisan command.Models help you to write relationship and keep your code clean ,also it will quicker compare to db queries

For example `php artisan make:model Branch`

**Branch Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Branch extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected  $table="table_branch";

    protected $guarded=['id'];

    public function roadName(){

        return $this->hasMany(RoadName::class);
    }
}
```

**RoadName model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RoadName extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table="roadname";

    protected $guarded=['id'];

}
```

In your controller

```
$branch=\App\Models\Branch::query()->find($id);
$roadName=[];
if(isset($request->roads)&&count($request->roads)){
    
foreach ($request->roads as $value){
    
$roadName[]=new \App\Models\RoadName(['roadname' =>  $value]);
        
}
  $branch->roadName()->saveMany($roadName);
}
```

`Note`: this created using laravel 8.

You can learn more about in official documentation

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given why I am getting this error

Comment: can you dd($request->roads); before foreach and show data

Comment: Sidenote, `foreach($request->input('roads', []) as $road)` is better syntax for handling this; if `$request->roads` is `null`, `$request->input('roads', [])` will use the fallback of an empty array `[]`, and the `foreach()` won't error. It won't do anything due to the array being empty, but that's better than an exception  You also won't need the `if()` check before the `foreach()` if you use that.

Comment: @TimLewis.THanks for mentioning :)

Comment: Its just a blank screen

Comment: @SamridhiSinha.You must pass data ,better add validation required to avoid errors

Comment: Its an empty array because I need to input the roadname into it. So what should I do now?

Comment: at branch id 1 I need to insert the roadname. Also the blade view (addroads)  will open at that particular id

Comment: enter roadnames in input